# Coffee Script Module with jQuery and underscore modules as argument

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

In a compiled coffee script our code automatically wrapped in a module like below:

```
(function() {
  //Code goes here
}).call(this);
```

But i want to wrap my code in a module like:

```
(function($, _) {
  //Code goes here
})(jQuery, _);
```

and

```
var myModule = (function($, _) {
                 //Code goes here
               })(jQuery, _);
```

So what i've to use for it in coffee Script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `do` for auto-invoking functions like these:

```
do ($ = jQuery, _ = _) ->
  # Code goes here
```

`do` itself is an expression (that evaluates to the last expression in its body, like any function call), so you can assign its value to a variable:

```
myModule = do ($ = jQuery, _ = _) ->
  # Code goes here
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(($, _) ->

#Code goes here
) jQuery, _
```

and

```
myModule = (($, _) ->

#Code goes here
)(jQuery, _)
```

http://js2coffee.org/

Comment: Also make sure to compile with `--bare` param so it doesn't add the closure by default.